# How to execute applications in existing X window from virtual console?

Tags: ssh, x11, xfce

I run Debian Wheezy and have Xfce as my X-Window Manager on virtual console 7, which starts up automatically.

Once I've logged on and I'm using the xfce interface, is it possible for me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and move to another virtual console (non-X, console 2), and start an application in my, already running, x-session on console 7?

Also, can I do this remotely: say I have a laptop running Linux with Xfce running at home. Can I start an application on that instance of Xfce over `ssh` from work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The program needs the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. In some more complex linux distributions you also need 2 other variables `$XAUTHORITY` and `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

For example type in the terminal:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xterm
```

If it is still not working export the 2 varibales:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-LoSJ0EDrKV,guid=d46a103f4e55832818aa23c80000219c
export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-user-6jbaaz/database
```

To find out the values of those variables, type `echo VARIABLE` in the graphic session.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, that is very similar to Debian, you can do

```
DISPLAY=:0 xterm &
```

Also, after connecting to the ssh server you can perform the same command.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but Xfce is red herring. It is all about X11.

Any X11 application needs two things to connect to a display server (which provides keyboard, video and mouse to the application), it needs to know which server and it needs permission.

In the common case of connecting to the local X server it has the name :0 which means local host first display. In most cases you can tell your application the name of the server to use either on the command line (commonly -display or --display, but it may vary) or by setting the DISPLAY environment variable.

Authorization is typically provided in the ~/.Xauthority file, but if it is somewhere else the XAUTHORITY variable will tell you where.